# Laravel : how to get database value in my java script variable?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

i am new laravel ...facing problem in getting value in javscript variable below code :

```
 var id = $("#question_id").html('{{ $value->question_id }}');
```

Using div in blade part

```
<div id="question_id">{{ $value->question_id }}</div>
```

how to get question id in var id?Getting error value not define i use foreach loop it shows nothing? how to proceed?

Comment: make sure that the controller is passing the variable to the view that includes this script

Comment: yes that  blade view getting variable from controller ?

Comment: getting this : w.fn.init [div#question_id] in console when is print console.log(id);

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use data attributes to pass variables

```
<div id="question_id" data-field-id="{{ $value->question_id }}"></div>

<script>
    var id = $("#question_id").data("field-id");
</script>
```

It is still possible that some of this will work:

```
var id = $("#question_id").html("{{ $value->question_id }}");
var id = $("#question_id").html("{!! $value->question_id !!}");
var id = $("#question_id").html(<?php echo $value->question_id; ?>);
```

Comment: what data-field-id means here?

Comment: how i can get my previous page id value ? in javascript variable

Answer (score 0):

You can use in JS

```
var id = $("#question_id").text();
```

Comment: it shows undefined until i put that into foreach loop  like                                                         @foreach($getquestions as $value)
         
        var id = $("#question_id").html ('{{ $value->question_id }}');
        
@endforeach